# Unable to automate login api using rest-assured. I am getting following error: {"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

I am new to rest assure, I am trying to automate login API using Rest Assured. But I am not able to do it. I am getting following error:
**{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}**

```
@Test
    public void test101(){

        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
        Response resp= given().auth().preemptive().basic("username@gmail.com", 
       "password").when().post("https://app.test.com/api/users/login.json");
        System.out.println(resp.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(resp.asString());
}
```

API is working fine, if I try to get the response using POSTMAN.

Comment: `.basic()` auth is for htaccess user and password, not a payload sent to your api. Need to send an actual payload (assuming json).

Comment: In Postman, try clicking Preview Request to see if there are other headers or params etc being passed. Sometimes Postman does this for you automatically but you'll have to do them manually in RestAssured. https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization